# StackPanel could not be found (missing assembly reference)

Tags: c#, .net

I want to start a new StackPanel in Windows Application, But I can not find the assembly reference in visual studio 2015. please help me, is there any solution to auto look for missing assembly reference. Many Thanks

StackPanel sp = new StackPanel();

Comment: did you create a WPF application?

Comment: If it is not a wpf application add `PresentationCore.dll` and `PresentationFramework.dll` to your project references.

Comment: Thanks @MitatKoyuncu. It works like a charm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add Reference to

> `PresentationFramework.dll`

then use the namespace

> Namespace:  System.Windows.Controls
>
> Assembly:  PresentationFramework (in PresentationFramework.dll)

Comment: The namespace alone isn't very helpful as VS will normally prompt you to resolve namespaces in known assemblies and you can't add a namespace without knowing which assembly it's in.

Comment: Hi James, I can not find System.Windows.Control. only can find System.Windoes.Forms.

Comment: @user3008989 find the edit. add the referance to PresentationFramework.dll which contains the namespace System.Windows.Controls