# The type 'StackPanel' was not found in Visual Studio for Mac

Tags: c#, xaml, visual-studio-mac, assembly-references

Photos of the code:
[The error: ContentPage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JCJ0r.jpg)

[Cs file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jmC5n.png)

[Xaml file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IABJe.png)

[another css file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WEh7j.png)

I am new to Visual Studio for Mac(building my first project here). So far everything was going just fine, but when I tried to utilise `<StackPanel> </StackPanel>` - I ran into a problem. The  is underlined with red, and I received an error that < The type 'StackPanel' was not found.Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built.>

Additional information: File's form: File.xaml

Could you please indicate which assembly or package should I install to eliminate the error? And also specify the way to execute your instructions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[StackPanel could not be found (missing assembly reference)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31858665/stackpanel-could-not-be-found-missing-assembly-reference)

Not entirely sure but you can try to add the PresentationFramework reference in your project references

[image: Open project references]

[image: Add PresentationFramework]

If that doesn't help read this post and it's comment:
[The type was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71626473/the-type-was-not-found-verify-that-you-are-not-missing-an-assembly-reference-an)

Try adding the reference in your code with something like this

```
<Window x:Class="YourClassName"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="StackPanel" Height="160" Width="300">
```

Some links:

https://www.infragistics.com/help/wpf/adding-assembly-to-a-visual-studio-project

https://wpf-tutorial.com/panels/stackpanel/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/xaml-namespaces-and-namespace-mapping-for-wpf-xaml?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

Hope these can help explain a bit more

Comment: Hey! I successfully downloaded the file from the NuGet and added it to my References. It's still underlined. Is there anything I missed, maybe I should somehow initialise it in code? What I'm implying is, are there any other procedures that I should go through in order to ensure the functionality of the given assembly?

Comment: Moreover, I checked the last link as well, and I don't think that the version of the Visual Studio is responsible for this glitch. I have the latest existing version of the program.

Comment: I've searched around a bit and found a few links. My theory right now is that your code doesn't reference the namespace yet. Try adding `xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"` to your top level tag. I've added a few more links in my answer. If that still doesn't help it would be helpful if you provided some code and your project type.

Comment: I appreciate your help, as requested I added to my previous post some screenshots of the code, along with all the included libraries and assemblies. When I ran the program the stackpanel error vanished, whilst another has appeared(something to do with the ContentPage(please see the attached photos in the post)). I was hoping you could help me resolve that issue as well, maybe there is another assembly that I am missing? Almost forgot to mention, my project type is a mobile app(both for android and ios).

Comment: Thank you for those additions. I saw two things in your screenshots. First, the issue with the content page, I don't know what error exactly appears but I suspect is has to do with the `Width` and `Height` tags you added to the `<ContentPage>`. According to https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.contentpage?view=xamarin-forms, these Tags in ContentPage are read-only, so you can't set them in code. The other thing I saw is a missing semicolon on line 12 of your App.cs. Could you also provide the exact error messages as you did with the StackPanel if it still doesn't work?

Comment: Right, it still gives out the same error, even after I got rid of the Height and Width. I attached the screenshot of the error in the main post.I hope it will help resolve the problem.

Comment: Seems to be something more complicated, which I am not experienced enough to help you with. Sorry to disappoint. The issue could be solved by simply running Clean and Rebuild so I would try doing that if you haven't already. This might also be a helpful link: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/11101#issuecomment-678329339

Comment: Thanks, anyway. You did help me resolve the other error. I'd already run the Clean and Rebuild, didn't fix the error. I'll browse through the internet a bit more, I might spot sth useful.